# LINQ sort dictionary by value

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to sort values Descending before pushing them into dictionary. The query works fine but i just need to add sorting functionality.

Following is my original LINQ query

```
        List<Model> list = query1.Where(x => x.ItemsPrice.Any())
            .GroupBy(x => new { Student = query2.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x. Id).Student.Name })
            .Select(x => new Model
            {
                StudentName = x.Key.Student,
                ClassItems = x.SelectMany(y => y. ItemsPrice)
                              .GroupBy(y => y. Price.item.Name)
                              .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Sum(z => z.TotalPrice()))
            }).ToList();
```

I am trying the following code but it is giving this error

> can not implicitly convert IOrderedEnumerables to System.Collection.Generic.Dictioanry.

```
.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Sum(z => z.TotalPrice())).OrderByDescending(y => y.Value)
```

Comment: you cant. have you considered using a sorted dictionery?

Comment: I am very curious why you would want to sort a dictionary? The order doesn't matter one bit for accessing the data, so the only other reason I can imagine is presentation. If you are trying to render the dictionary, why not just flatten it to a list?

Comment: @ Nathan, you have very valid point. All i need it for my presentation. I could have done it very easily on client side but we need to return sorted dictionary from the server... Does it have any performance issue??

Comment: @immirza The performance implications would be negligible, you can project the dictionary to a List<KeyValuePair<T, TU>> and then sort by the value. Same exact data structure, without the advantage of the hashed indexes. If the consumer needs to turn it back into a dictionary, the operation is equally trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for you:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<int>
{
  public int Compare(int x, int y)
  {
    return x.CompareTo(y);
  }
}

// ...
private void DoStuff()
{
  var dict = new Dictionary<int, int> {{3, 300}, {2, 200}};
  var sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<int, int>(dict, new MyComparer());
}
```

Or in your specific scenario:

```
private class DescendingComparer : IComparer<string>
{
  int IComparer<string>.Compare(string a, string b)
  {              
    return StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(b, a);
  }
}

// ....
ClassItems = new SortedDictionary<string, float>(x.SelectMany(y => y. ItemsPrice)
                                                .GroupBy(y => y. Price.item.Name)
                                                .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Sum(z => z.TotalPrice())),
                                               new DescendingComparer());
```

Note: adjust the key and value type of the sorted dictionary as well as the comparer type according to your needs!

Comment: You shouldn't use subtraction to compare integers; it breaks when `int.MinValue` is involved.

Comment: @Markus, thank a lot but i have acheived the same thing with minor change in my query and that is i am select new and sorting by key before pushing in Dictionary here is my modified code : x.SelectMany(y => y. ItemsPrice)
                                                .GroupBy(y => y. Price.item.Name)
      .Select(y => new
                        {   
                            Name = y.Key,
                            Cost = y.Sum(z => z.Cost())
                        }).OrderByDescending(y => y.Cost)
                                                .ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Cost),

Comment: @Servy: thanks for the hint! I've fixed it with a fu*gly ternary operator :)
@ immirza: I expected that something like that would be possible but then one needs a context ;)

Comment: @Markus Just use the `CompareTo` to compare integers.

Comment: @Servy: and again thank you! That looks much better :P

Comment: You don't need a custom comparer if you're just going to compare the two values normally.

Comment: @servy: Yeah I know - it was initially thought to show the possibility to use a custom comparer - its questionable now ...

Answer (score 1):

The order that items are stored in a dictionary is not guaranteed.  Don't rely on it.  When you retrieve items from the dictionary, you can sort it at that point.

> "For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined."
>
> -- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

As Markus pointed out, if you really need order in your dictionary, use the [`OrderedDictionary<,>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or the [`SortedDictionary<,>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: There is an OrderedDictionary ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and even a SortedDictionary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Markus, Thanks, I wasn't aware of those.  Guess I've never had a need for order in a dictionary.

Comment: @Markus, i am not sure how i can use OrderedDictionary or SortedDictionary in my current LINQ query... do you have idea?

Comment: @immirza: Have a look in my answer I just updated it accordingly ... but maybe you need to make some adjustments according to your scenario and later usage of the data structure ...

Comment: Okay, i tried this  ClassItems =  new SortedDictionary<string, float>(x.SelectMany(y => y. ItemsPrice)
                              .GroupBy(y => y. Price.item.Name)
                              .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Sum(z => z.TotalPrice())), new DescendingComparer()) but getting error Error 41 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<string,float>.SortedDictionary(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,float>, System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<string>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @immirza: first of all we are discussing this in the wrong thread => I do not get updates if you don't mention me. And to answer your question: I assume you forgot to adjust the comparer to be a string comparer ...

Comment: @immirza: I've adjusted my answer according to the types provided in your previous error message ...

Comment: @Markus, thank a lot but i have achieved the same thing with minor change in my query and that is i am selecting new and sorting by key before pushing in Dictionary here is my modified code : x.SelectMany(y => y. ItemsPrice) .GroupBy(y => y. Price.item.Name) .Select(y => new { Name = y.Key, Cost = y.Sum(z => z.Cost()) }).OrderByDescending(y => y.Cost) .ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Cost),